# Можно ли натянуть вёрстку на wordpress только на одну страницу сайта

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка, cms

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть сайт:

- index.php
- about.php
- blog.php
- И так далее////

Будет ли корректно натянуть wp, только на страницу blog.php ?
Т.е создать отдельную папку для блога.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Будет ли корректно натянуть wp, только на страницу blog.php?

В принципе можно так сделать, но смысл?..

Тем более, что WordPress прекрасно поддерживает и статические страницы и редактировать их через него гораздо проще.

Я бы сделал blog рубрикой со статьями, а остальное статическими страницами. Как-то так...